# Using Bitmap to Convert Images from colour to black & white - Space Issue : c#

Tags: c#, .net

I think this might be repeated but the code is not:
I used the following code to convert images from jpg color to jpg b&w.
TH eproblem is that my color jpg is of size 500KB, but my converted b&w jpg is 2.18MB, how to optimize the size of this conversion.

```
public void ConvertBlackAndWhiteImage()
      {
           System.Drawing.Bitmap originalImage = null;
           originalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\Users\anvesh.veerelli\Pictures\ash 3.jpg");
           System.Drawing.Color c;

           for (int i = 0; i < originalImage.Width; i++)
           {
                for (int j = 0; j < originalImage.Height; j++)
                {
                     c = originalImage.GetPixel(i, j);
                     int r = 0;
                     r = Convert.ToInt16(c.R);
                     int g = 0;
                     g = Convert.ToInt16(c.G);
                     int b = 0;
                     b = Convert.ToInt16(c.B);
                     int ans = (r + g + b) / 3;
                     if (ans > 128)
                     {
                          r = 255;
                          g = 255;
                          b = 255;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          r = 0;
                          g = 0;
                          b = 0;
                     }
                     c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                     originalImage.SetPixel(i, j, c);

                }
           }
           string tmpFileName = @"C:\Users\anvesh.veerelli\Pictures\Destination\test.jpg";
           originalImage.Save(tmpFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
      }
```

Comment: You're saving it as a BMP.

Comment: Try saving in `ImageFormat.jpeg`

Comment: Its sort of obvious you copied the code when you say `to b&w jpg` when you are saving as `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your output `ImageFormat` to Jpeg.
Even though your filename is JPEG the internal format of the picture is BMP.

So your last line becomes:

```
originalImage.Save("", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```